# Least squares fit to sinusoidal power series

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a function of form:

[image]

where A and B are fixed constants. In scipy, my usual (and I think reasonably canonical) approach to such problems goes like so:

```
def func(t, coefs):
    phase = np.poly1d(coefs)(t)
    return A * np.cos(phase) + B

def fit(time, data, guess_coefs): 
    residuals = lambda p: func(time, p) - data
    fit_coefs = scipy.optimize.leastsq(residuals, guess_coefs) 
    return fit_coefs
```

This works OK, but I'd like to supply an analytic Jacobian to improve convergence. Thus:

```
def jacobian(t, coefs):
    phase = np.poly1d(coefs, t)
    the_jacobian = []
    for i in np.arange(len(coefs)):
        the_jac.append(-A*np.sin(phase)*(t**i))
    return the_jac

def fit(time, data, guess_coefs):
    residuals = lambda p: func(time, p) - data
    jac = lambda p: jacobian(time, p)
    fit_coefs = scipy.optimize.leastsq(residuals, guess_coefs, 
                                       Dfun=jac, col_deriv=True)
```

This doesn't work as well, even at orders of 2 or less. Neither does a quick check with optimize.check_gradient() give positive results.

I'm almost certain the Jacobian and the code are correct (although please correct me) and that the problem is more fundamental: the t**i term in the Jacobian causes overflow errors. This isn't a problem in the function itself, because here the monomial terms are multiplied by their coefficients, which are very small.

My questions are:

1. Is there something wrong code-wise with what I've done above?
2. Or is there some other problem?
3. If my hypothesis is correct, is there a way to precondition the fit-function so the Jacobian is better-behaved? Maybe I could fit to logarithms of the data and time, or something.

Thanks!

Edit: forgot the square in the original functional form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `poly1D` function has the highest coefficient first, while your jacobian function assumes the lowest coefficient first. If in `jacobian` you make the return statement `return the_jac[::-1]` (and also fix the more obvious typos) your functions will pass `optimize.check_gradient()` and work correctly in `leastsq()`.

Your further question about numerical stability is also warranted here. If you have large values of *t* and large numbers of coefficients, you could very easily have numerical accuracy issues: for example, in 32-bit precision, if your polynomial evaluates to over about 10^8, the phase of the sinusoid will be entirely lost in the mantissa and the result of the sine evaluation will be basically garbage!

You could address this by using *modular exponentiation* within the polynomial: essentially all you care about in each term of the polynomial is `(a_k t ** k) % p`, where `p = 2 * np.pi` is the period of the sinusoid. You can compute this modular exponential to higher precision for large `t` with `(a_k * (t % (p / a_k)) ** k) % p`; for accuracy at large `k` as well, things get a bit more complicated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514565/numpy-matrix-power-exponent-with-modulo) for a nice discussion of such things.