# Why does 2 raised to x give negative value as x increases in numpy?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, complexity-theory

Numpy is giving array containing list of 2 raised to natural numbers as negative values. How can 2 raised to positive numbers like 1000 be negative?

I have an array 'x' that we use to plot x-axis value from 1 to n. 
We take x**(2**x) i.e x raised to (2 raised to x) for each value in array x and use it as y axis value.

Case 1:  For x ∈ [1, 50)

I have used the code below, and the output is proper as there are no negative values in the output of np.power(2, x).

```
x = np.array([x for x in range(1, 50)])

print(np.power(2, x))
x2x =  np.power(x, np.power(2, x)) 


plt.plot(x, x, label = 'f(n) = n')
plt.plot(x, x2x, label = 'f(n) = x**(2**x)')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: No negative values in the output]

[Link to output](https://github.com/aishwarya34/AlgorithmsIlluminated/blob/master/images/so_issue1.png)

Case 2:  For x ∈ [1, 100)

I have used the code below, and the output is having negative values in the output of np.power(2, x) and so np.power(x, np.power(2, x))

```
x = np.array([x for x in range(1, 100)])

print(np.power(2, x))
x2x =  np.power(x, np.power(2, x)) 


plt.plot(x, x, label = 'f(n) = n')
plt.plot(x, x2x, label = 'f(n) = x**(2**x)')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Negative values in the output]

[Link to output](https://github.com/aishwarya34/AlgorithmsIlluminated/blob/master/images/so_issue2.png)

If x is always positive and non-decreasing and 2 is constant and positive then why is 2 raised to positive number getting negative output in numpy?

Comment: This sounds like simple integer overflow and wraparound.  Your output isn't in the posting; how do the values in question compare with standard MAXINT values?

Comment: `np.int32(2) ** np.int32(31)` → -2147483648. `np.int64(2) ** np.int64(63)` →
-9223372036854775808

Comment: even `np.int64` won't solve for every case: `np.int64(9801)**np.int64(99) 
 -8755237408081528679`

Comment: This is a known issue https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10964

Answer (score 0):

The integers are likely overflowing. 32-bit integers can only contain values up to ~2.1b, and if it overflows it will wrap back around into the negatives.

Setting `dtype=int64` may fix your issue. If not, just use python integers (`dtype=object`). They're not very efficient but they can hold as much data as your memory will allow.

Comment: did you try dtype=object?

Comment: The overflow still occurs even after using x**(2**x) or dtype=np.int64. While dtype=object does get positive values for higher powers, it works incredibly slow with numpy and the code freezes.

Comment: Python integers are slower but they're you're only option if you're calculating values above 2^63.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Python's power operator (**) for your purpose as even changing numpy dtype to int64 won't help when the size exceeds 64 bits. Whereas Python's power operator will suffice your purpose.

```
x**(2**x)
```

Comment: The overflow still occurs even after using x**(2**x) and  dtype=np.int64

Answer (score 0):

There's 3 cases that you may be inquiring about.

## Case 1: You just care about the *most* significant digits

Use floats. Cast everything to a `double`-precision float and it should be fine up to about 10<sup>300</sup>.

```
>>> 3 ** np.array([2, 10, 50, 100], dtype=np.float)
array([9.00000000e+00, 5.90490000e+04, 7.17897988e+23, 5.15377521e+47])
```

If you're exceeding that, only store the logarithm of the numbers, and use the respective math (adding logs = multiplication, multiplying logs = exponentiation), then you're fine up to ludicrously high numbers.

```
>>> math.log(3) * 50
54.93061443340549
>>> math.log(3) * 50 == math.log(3 ** 50) == math.log(717897987691852588770249)
True
```

## Case 2: You only care about the *least* significant digits

I think this is called "finite field" or "Galois" math? Generally useful in cryptography and other things. Unfortunately, Numpy doesn't seem to have a power/modulo function, so you'd need to roll your own or [try a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514565/numpy-matrix-power-exponent-with-modulo) (the ones there only work if it doesn't overflow in a single op, so may not work again).

```
>>> [pow(3, n, 2 ** 16 + 1) for n in [2, 10, 50, 100]]  # modulo some random prime
[9, 59049, 12911, 33330]
```

## Case 3: You need *all* the digits

You must use 'bigint' math, which Numpy does not provide. Python integers are the easy choice.

```
>>> 3 ** np.array([2, 10, 50, 100], dtype=np.object)
array([9, 59049, 717897987691852588770249,
       515377520732011331036461129765621272702107522001], dtype=object)
```