# Three argument pow for arrays

Tags: python, numpy, math, pow, modular-arithmetic

[`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) accepts a third argument for modulo `pow(x, y, z)` that is more efficient computation than `x ** y % z`. How can you do that with arrays?  What I've tried:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array(range(10))
>>> pow(A, 23, 13)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'numpy.ndarray', 'int', 'int'
```

Though ndarray implements `__pow__`, invoking directly doesn't do anything:

```
>>> A.__pow__(23, 13)
NotImplemented
```

Using the exponentiation and modulo in two step gives incorrect results (guess it is overflowing the dtype)

```
>>> print(*(A ** 23 % 13))  # wrong result!
0 1 7 9 10 8 11 12 0 6
>>> print(*[pow(int(a), 23, 13) for a in A])  # correct result
0 1 7 9 10 8 11 2 5 3
```

The actual array is large so I can not use dtype "object" nor have the looping directly in Python.

How to compute 3-arg pow for numpy arrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy matrix power/exponent with modulo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514565/numpy-matrix-power-exponent-with-modulo) It seems unsupported yet by Numpy. However, this may be a good idea to ask for this function to be added in Numpy.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: No, that's a matrix power, while this question is asking for an elementwise power.

Answer (score 0):

Find the greatest n such that 2^n is not greater than your exponent. Then calculate A^{2^n} by repeatedly squaring and taking modulus for n steps. Then multiply this matrix with the matrix you obtain by recursively calling this same algorithm for `(your exponent - 2^n)`.

I know this makes many calls but since the most operations are running in Numpy, it is probably fast. You can record the matrices `A^{2^n} (mod k)` to make it even faster. Observe that the number of recursive calls is at most `log_2(exponent)+1`.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't it true that even one squaring can cause an overflow?

Comment: @nosteponsnek Yes it can, if the values in the array are big enough. However you can avoid that by increasing the precision and range of the datatype you are using (e.g. use double precision instead of float). However the real problem here is that even if the values are small, exponentiation can cause an overflow very quickly. This method makes sure that it does not occur by repeatedly taking modulus after each squaring operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not find a better answer try the [idea suggested in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518147/4975981). The problem with your original solution is overflow of np.int64/np.float64 in numpy unlike int in python (which expands as much as your available memory)

```
((A ** 13 % 13) * (A ** 10 % 13)) % 13
```

output:

```
array([ 0,  1,  7,  9, 10,  8, 11,  2,  5,  3])
```

If your array overflows, you would need to break down power to smaller elements so that it does not over flow. For example, you can break into smaller pieces like this:

```
n = 1
B = A % 13
while 2*n < 23:
    B = B * B % 13
    n *= 2
B = B * (A ** (23-n) % 13) % 13
B
```

Comment: I've only used `A = np.array(range(10))` as a simple example.  This still overflows `A = np.array(range(40))`!

Comment: @nosteponsnek use the same idea to break down the power into smaller numbers such that it does not overflow. I added an edit for an example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map()` and lambda to accomplish this. You can then consume the results one at a time. Try:

```py
result_iter = map(lambda x: pow(int(x), 23, 13), A))

results = list(result_iter)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 7, 9, 10, 8, 11, 2, 5, 3]
```

Comment: This works but it would be much slower with respect to a vectorized solution in numpy.

Comment: This is basically looping over array (might even be slower than plain loop)